# invalid_grant error - PowerShell Azure PartnerCenter Get-PartnerCustomer API call

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, microsoft-partner-center

I am trying to write a script in PowerShell ISE (5.1) that retrieves all customers using the PartnerCenter Powershell. My script is:

```
type here# Azure AD Application Configuration
$tenantId = "HIDDEN"
$appId = "HIDDEN"
$appSecret = "HIDDEN"

# Partner Center API Configuration
$scope = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/.default"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = $scope
    client_id     = $appId
    client_secret = $appSecret
    resource      = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com"
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Headers     = @{ "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    Body        = $body
    Method      = "Post"
    URI         = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$token = $response.access_token

Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $token

# Get all customers
$customers = Get-PartnerCustomer
$customers
```

However, running this gives the following error:

```
Get-PartnerCustomer :  (invalid_grant)
At line:32 char:14
+ $customers = Get-PartnerCustomer
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-PartnerCustomer], PartnerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Store.PartnerCenter.PowerShell.Commands.GetPartnerCustomer
```

In the Azure Portal, the app is registered properly, I am sure the tenantid, appid and appsecret are correct and the following API permissions are added so that should be sufficient (and approved by admin):

[image: Added API permissions]

The problem is probably MFA. This can also be seen by running the following script:

```
# Azure AD Application Configuration
$tenantId = "HIDDEN"
$appId = "HIDDEN"
$appSecret = "HIDDEN"

# Connect to Partner Center using the access token
Connect-PartnerCenter

# Get Customers
$customers = Get-PartnerCustomer

# Display Customers
$customers
```

In this case, chrome opens, asks for login and afterwards MFA is requested. Doing this manually works and the customers are succesfully outputted as a result.
However I would like the script to connect automatically using the API keys without needing to login manually, and this `invalid_grant` error is probably caused due to the MFA.

Is there a simple way to fix this? Since it should be an easy script and I know this was possible in the past, before MFA was required, but now I just can't get it  to work. Keep getting the `invalid_grant error` Or is there maybe an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created one app registration and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran your script in my environment, I too got **same error** like this:

```bash
$tenantId = "HIDDEN"
$appId = "HIDDEN"
$appSecret = "HIDDEN"

# Partner Center API Configuration
$scope = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/.default"

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = $scope
    client_id     = $appId
    client_secret = $appSecret
    resource      = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com"
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Headers     = @{ "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    Body        = $body
    Method      = "Post"
    URI         = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$token = $response.access_token

Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $token

# Get all customers
$customers = Get-PartnerCustomer
$customers
```

**Response:**

[image]

> In the cases where MFA is enabled, you can make use of **refresh tokens** that will be valid for 90 days as an alternative.
>
> To get refresh token, you need to login with Partner Center user account manually **once** and can use it to generate access tokens.

I used below PowerShell script that gives **refresh token** in response after successful authentication.

```
$appId = "appId"
$appSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenantId = "tenantId" 
$credential = [PSCredential]::new($appId, $appSecret)

$tokenSplat = @{
    ApplicationId        = $appId
    Credential           = $credential
    Scopes               = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation"
    ServicePrincipal     = $true
    TenantId             = $tenantId
    UseAuthorizationCode = $true
}

$token = New-PartnerAccessToken @tokenSplat

$token.RefreshToken
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can now use this **refresh token** that is valid for **90 days** and connect to Partner Center like this:

```
$connectSplat = @{
    ApplicationId = $appId
    Credential    = $credential
    RefreshToken  = $token.RefreshToken
}

Connect-PartnerCenter @connectSplat

Get-PartnerRole
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Generate Microsoft Partner Center Refresh Token – moiaune.dev by **Mads Moi-Aune**](https://moiaune.dev/2021/11/03/generate-microsoft-partner-center-refresh-token/)