How to authenticate to Microsoft Partner Center using Azure Automation?
I have the following PowerShell script in Azure Automation. It needs to connect to Partner Center.
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com").Token

Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $accessToken

The Azure Automation account is using a system-assigned managed identity.

Can you use this managed identity to give it Partner Center permissions? If so, how?
Or do we have to create an Azure AD app registration? What app permissions are required?
Is there another way?

The script needs to run in Azure Automation not as sign-in user. Is this possible?
The scope of the script will be to:

Pull all customers from Partner Center

Pull all users from each customer

Pull all licenses for each user



The script "authenticates" to the Partner Center; however, running Get-PartnerCustomer after results in Error: Get-PartnerCustomer : (invalid_grant). I am assuming this is because the managed identity does not have any Partner Center permissions.

Yes you need to create an application and generate access token to call Partner API. Refer this MsDoc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/partner-center-authentication

According to this MsDoc, you need to create a Microsoft Entra ID application to authenticate Partner Center.
Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions like below:

Now to connect to Partner Center, use the below script:
$appId = "ClientID"
$appSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenantId = "TenantID" 
$credential = [PSCredential]::new($appId, $appSecret)

$tokenSplat = @{
    ApplicationId        = $appId
    Credential           = $credential
    Scopes               = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation"
    ServicePrincipal     = $true
    TenantId             = $tenantId
    UseAuthorizationCode = $true
}

$token = New-PartnerAccessToken @tokenSplat

$token.RefreshToken



Now connect to Partner Center:
$connectSplat = @{
    ApplicationId = $appId
    Credential    = $credential
    RefreshToken  = $token.RefreshToken
}

Connect-PartnerCenter @connectSplat


For sample, I executed the below command:
Get-PartnerRole


References:
azure - Microsoft partner API: can't authenticate - Stack Overflow by matey-dzhigoshev
partner-rest/partner-rest/develop/api-authentication.md at docs · MicrosoftDocs/partner-rest · GitHub

Hi Rukmini, this script needs to run in the background (in Azure Automation). Will it be required to sign-in each time?

Yes the script is required sign in each time

Is there anyway to have it as app-only authentication? This will be running in Azure Automation and we won't be able to sign-in. Appreciate your help.

You want to use identity or application?

Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78147979/invalid-grant-error-powershell-azure-partnercenter-get-partnercustomer-api-cal

Did the above reference work for you?
